# Header getting over the page content

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am having trouble with the top menu of my page. It keeps getting over the rest of the page. Here where you can have a better look of the problem. http://blog.sondortravel.com/albania-to-macedonia/ 
Any idead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove this style

```
.content {
    margin-top: -46px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take away the margin-top: -46px; in your stylesheet.

Row: 46 in style_dynamic.css

Also i really dont think this belongs on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

change your div.content.
current:

```
<div class="content " style="min-height: 586px; padding-top: 0px;">
```

new:

```
<div class="content " style="min-height: 586px; padding-top: 0px; margin-top: 20px">
```

20px not must. change whatever value you want.